# Why doesn't sunlight ALWAYS get split (into monochromatic) when going through the clouds?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, refraction

It is my understanding that clouds are largely made up of water, which is known to split white light into its frequency components, and that's why we see rainbows sometimes. My question is, with sunlight being practically constant throughout the day, why aren't there rainbows all over, all the time? I mean, we can see monochromatic changes in the color of the "sky" throughout the day, but rainbows seem to only happen sometimes, why?

**In short:** Rainbows that we can see come from water droplets, not collections of droplets.

Comment: This is probably interesting to you:

http://what-if.xkcd.com/150/

Comment: short answer: rainbows are formed by drops of water, not just water.

Comment: Visit the [Atmospheric Optics](http://www.atoptics.co.uk) web site. The answers to your question are there, along with many gorgeous pictures of various kinds of atmospheric optics.

Comment: Have you ever seen a rainbow over a water fountain? It comes from the mist .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light is multiply scattered in clouds, i.e. it is refracted by one water droplet or ice crystal, then refracted again by the next, then again by the next and so on. By the time the light reaches you eyes it will have been scattered many times. This means all the light hitting the cloud gets thoroughly mixed up and all the rainbows are jumbled up together and just appear a uniform white.

To get a rainbow requires that the light scattering be fairly weak so the light scattered into the rainbow arc is not scattered again.

Comment: So, you're saying that multiple scattering will reconstruct the white light? Not doubting you just clarifying. I understand there can be constructive interference, but I was given to understand that it applies to the magnitude and not the frequency components.

Comment: Even when flying at local could-level or just above, I still don't think I see anymore rainbows than on the surface of the earth.

Comment: @MBarbosa: you get a rainbow because a single droplet scatters the light at around 42°, but the blue light is scattered a bit more than this and the red light is scattered a bit less. But in a cloud the light scattered at 42° is scattered again, then again and again until the scattering is effectively in random directions. This applies to all the individual frequencies of light, so for all the frequencies the scattering is isotropic.

Comment: So you think above cloud level the water content is just too low for all over rainbows? I am actually not even sure there is any water above the clouds but I am assuming so.

Comment: @MBarbosa: I haven't flown recently, but my recollection is that when you get above the top of the clouds the air is usually very clear. You could probably get rainbows right at the top edge of the cloud as it's thinning out, but you, the cloud and the Sun would need to be aligned just right.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a rainbow is when the incoming white light comes from a very small bright source, like when the sky is very clear in one direction and the sun shines in from that direction to the rain under the clouds on the opposite side from where you are looking.
If the light source is diffuse, then you get lots of rainbows all jumbled together into uniform white light so you don't see any of them.

Comment: Is this similar to how acoustic "white" noise is actually just random noise superposed? Thanks.

Comment: @MBarbosa: Well, I guess so, although you could get the same effect if it wasn't random. (There's something called a Sobol sequence that isn't random, in fact it's smoother than random, that could produce the same effect. What you have here is a smooth function, not a collection of point sources.)

Comment: Nice! I had not heard of that! Although it seems that in nature these things would be Stochastic.

Comment: @MBarbosa: Ever heard of convolution? A stochastic approximation would be if the light source consisted of many point sources. Maybe in some deep sense it is, but it is more common in the real world to treat a diffuse light source as a continuous distribution function, and convolve with that.

Comment: Yep! I work in Computational EM and most of the time we model light as tiny point sources. But it makes sense that this would be a convolution of continuous functions. Thanks!